# Unable boot into Linux after BIOS update (dual boot machine)

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot, bios

My notebook has dual boot setup using UEFI mode. Windows 10 (installed by default) and Linux Mint 19.3. It was running ok until a new BIOS update made by Lenovo Vantage. After updating BIOS in Windows I can't login to Linux Mint installation because it stops at grub terminal black screen. If I change boot order I can login Windows without problem.

I tried boot-repair using a bootable USB but with no success. Here is boot-repair log after so many tries (updated): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kCbx2zXHmw/

Previous log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ndfhCWrYNC/

I read many posts in some forums about recovering grub but none helped. I compared it to another similar installation (notebook, same OS setup) and it seems to me that grub is not mounting/recognizing the correct partitions. Is there any solution without reinstalling any OS. Is it possible just to fix grub?

Thanks.

EDITED

If I boot using Linux option stops here:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling UEFI boot and Secure Boot in the BIOS and then booting into your Mint installation?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak why would disabling UEFI boot and Secure Boot in the BIOS cripple his setup? It would just test if the BIOS sees a valid MBR on his Mint partition. Additionally, he can always re-enable UEFI and Secure Boot anytime. There are no permanent effects.

Comment: SecureBoot disabled says the log,.. are the drives set to be in AHCI mode?

Comment: Both systems were installed in UEFI mode, so I left it enabled. Secure boot is disabled (but I can remember if it was enabled at installation) . I didn't chance Storage Controller Mode, it is in AHCI mode.

Comment: When it stops at the Grub terminal, are you able to interact with the terminal at all? If so, could you paste the output of ```ls /grub/```?

Comment: @Chuck Added an image to the post

Comment: Thanks! If you do ```ls /(hd0)/``` or ```ls /(hd1)/``` do you see any folder called ```grub```? If so, can you do ```ls /(hdX)/grub/``` where X is the drive number?

Comment: It returns: error: file `/grub/` not found.

Comment: I am not an expert, of course it depends on each case, but I compared it with another installation I have and it seems that the EFI partition (hd1,gpt1) is not mounted on the partition where the Linux filesystem (hd1,gpt5) is located at /boot/efi/EFI/.

Comment: UEFI update often resets UEFI settings. You orginally had Lupus Lite as default boot, which you still have? Or was that issue. Boot-Repair shows grub reinstalled & Ubuntu now is default boot. Please use newer Boot-Repair using ppa in your Ubuntu live installer as it now fully supports NVMe drives. Before it only showed some info.

Comment: @oldfred I can't say about Lupus. The installation ran with the configuration that grub did when installing Lunix Mint. Probably some update by grub-customizer. Everything was ok until the BIOS update. I updated the post link with the boot-repair log. I used liveUSB from the latest version of LM. I noticed that it is also a more recent version of boot-repair. If I try to update this app it gives an error, opens but does not perform the repair.

Comment: You still show Linpus & Mint as UEFI boot options which may not work. Ubuntu is now showing as default. If you used grub-customizer, use Boot-Repairs advanced options and a full reinstall of grub. Also use ppa to add Boot-Repair as newest version supports NVMe drives a lot better.

Comment: I think I found a issue with way Linux Mint deal with grub. Boot-repair log line 3029:/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/grub/fonts/UbuntuMono16.pf2'.

Comment: Try this link to boot into Linux https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/03/booting-gnulinux-manually-with-grub-prompt.html
Than install boot-repair tool by adding a new repository(Google it) and run boot-repair.
Worked for me.